# Positioning input within div

Tags: html, css, input

I have a `div` **container**. Between this `div` i have another `div` named **model** and there is a `input` ***file*** type. 
Now when i open up this in my **mozilla firefox** browser all are looks good. Problem is when i clicked `Browse...` then it's didn't open to upload a file, but when i clicked outside of `Browse...` field then it open to upload a file. Here is my html file

```css
 input{
          margin-bottom: 15px;
          padding: 10px;
          width: 100%;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border-radius: 5px;
          height: 50px;
          border:0px; 
          font-family: georgia;
          font-size: 12pt;
          text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="model">
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>Profile Picture</label>
            <input type="file" name="img">
          </div>
        </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

I google it but didn't find any good resource that's helpful for this problem . Sugesstion please . Thank you !

Comment: Which Firefox version did you get the problem? I tested on Firefox Quantumn latest & it works fine.

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 59.0.2

Comment: If you give me any good resourse about positionig div and others element then it's must be helpful for me . i want to learn it !

Comment: You can check out this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp but your code seems to be working fine on firefox

Comment: You can learn more from css-tricks.com. The issue you're facing may related to z-index. It could be the case that something overlap the button or it's outside the clickable area.

Comment: Now i try it crome . now problem is changed . when i clicked Browse then it open but also open it outside of browse.

Comment: @ToanLu  thanks . I have no knowledge about z-index !

Comment: @Rafsan It even works outsite the browse button because you're setting style for the button as `width: 100%`. You should just set a specific width as @Aryan show below.
Besides, it's better to add `cursor: pointer;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your CSS code a bit. Try this.

```
 input {
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   margin-top: 15px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-radius: 5px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 0px;
   font-family: georgia;
   font-size: 12pt;
   display: block;
 }
```

Comment: According to your `css`. now problem is changed . when i clicked Browse then it open but also open it outside of browse

Answer (score 0):

As a way to debug the area of the button, you can use the `outline` attribute.
You set the `width: 100%`, so it takes the whole line as a block.

Adding the `outline` attribute and you may see it.

```css
 input{
          margin-bottom: 15px;
          width: 85px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border-radius: 5px;
          height: 40px;
          border:0px; 
          font-family: georgia;
          font-size: 12pt;
          text-align: center;
          outline: 1px solid #FF0000;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="model">
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>Profile Picture</label>
            <input type="file" name="img">
          </div>
        </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's didn't solve my problem. i want that only `Browse...` area is clickable  . Your solution still clickable outside `Browse...` .

Comment: It's work in this case but if you work in this way then you didn't saw the file name that's uploaded ! by the way thank you